# How facebook App links work as deferred link on iOS

Tags: ios, deep-linking, applinks

How facebook app links or Tapstream deep links provide support for deferred links on iOS.
For example when app is not installed on device then it redirect to app store which is fine; but it also sends the data to app on installation which was there with link.

Comment: Why is this downvoted; i want to implement deferred linking without using any third party.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to pass data through the App Store, so all deferred deep linking works by using a remote server to close the loop. You can [build this yourself](https://blog.branch.io/how-to-build-a-linking-solution-for-every-device), but you really shouldn't for a lot of reasons, not the least of which being you have more important things to do. This is how Facebook and Tapstream provide deferred deep linking, and using third party tools for this is industry standard — even big names like Yelp and Tinder do so..

Facebook App Links are a completely different concept, and they have no support for deferred deep linking. They are essentially unsupported by any app on iOS (including Facebook) at this time, so they're not really worth your effort to implement.

The deferred deep link functionality provided by both Facebook and Tapstream is incomplete and unreliable. You should investigate a free service like [Branch.io](https://branch.io) (full disclosure: they're so awesome I work with them) or Firebase Dynamic Links to handle all of this for you.

Comment: Thanks! Yes I was exploring branch as well.